# Compare two filenames of first n characters in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

My requirement is

```
localfolder=green.txt,yellow.txt,blue.txt 
remotefolder=green_202105050333.txt,yellow_202105050333.txt,blue_202105050333.txt
```

I want to compare both folders as
IF[[localfolder==remotefolder]] ex: green.txt= green_202105050333.txt(here condition will look always first characters of each file or eliminating the data&time)
then
display the results as "matched"

kindly help me to get the logic here please.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please use CODE TAGS to make your samples more clear. Also add your tried code in your question, thank you.

Comment: thanks for your reply @RavinderSingh13, I want the code it self as requested based on my requirement. 1) check the condition like localfolder=remotefolder then cp filename to "matched" directory. 2) it should check only character of file, not consider the datetime while comparing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the next, create a file for each directory(folder), for example if you use *ls* :

```sh
# in local directory
ls localfolder > localFolder.txt
# in some remote directory
ls remoteFolder > remoteFolder.txt
```

We can suppose that files are the next:

localFolder.txt:

```
green.txt
yellow.txt
blue.txt
```

remoteFolder.txt:

```
green_202105050333.txt
yellow_202105050333.txt
blue_202105050333.txt
gray_202105050333.txt
```

Now put the files in the same directory and execute the next:

```sh
sed -r 's/\.[a-z]+//g' localFolder.txt | xargs -I{} grep {} remoteFolder.txt | sed -r 's/_[0-9]+//g'
```

The output will be:

```
green.txt
yellow.txt
blue.txt
```

Now if you want do it in script, then create a file for example myScript.sh and the content must be:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sed -r 's/\.[a-z]+//g' $1 | xargs -I{} grep {} $2 | sed -r 's/_[0-9]+//g'
```

Give execution permissions to the script:

```sh
chmod +x myScript.sh
```

And executed like the next:

```sh
./diff.sh localFolder.txt remoteFolder.txt
```

You will have the same result.

This script only works for your case and this is an explain what do each part

```sh
 # Remove .txt or any extensions for each line in localFolder
sed -r 's/\.[a-z]+//g' localFolder.txt 

# The ouput of each line is received by grep and search in remoteFolder
| xargs -I{} grep {} remoteFolder.txt

 # Remove the datetime
| sed -r 's/_[0-9]+//g'
```